# Why my app keep opening when I use shortcut in Python?

Tags: python, shortcut

I tried to create a program to open a app with a specific shortcut but when I press my keys it keep opening and didn't stop until I stopped the program

```
import keyboard
import time
import subprocess

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+space+b'):
        subprocess.Popen([r"C:\\Program Files\\Everything\\Everything.exe"])
        time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: how about `keyboard.add_hotkey` or `keyboard.wait('ctrl+space+b')`, and add a condition to check whether your app is open or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about try this code

```py
import keyboard
import subprocess
import threading

def run_my_program():
    subprocess.run([r"C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe"])

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+space+b'):
        threading.Thread(target=run_my_program).start()  # launch up the subprocess in parallel so input is not delayed
        while keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+space+b'):
            pass  # Wait until user lifts his hands off the keyboard
```